# Storing items in array list into database

Tags: mysql, arraylist

So basically I got three tables, cart, order and ordered product. For cart, I got cartID, productID, customerName, quantity. For Order, I got orderID, customerName, orderTotalPrice. For orderedProduct, I got orderedProductID, productID, orderedQuantity, orderID. So when user want to make payment, I will take the record in cart and store in an array list. Then I create a order but at the same time, I need to insert the items in cart into orderedProduct. Here is how I get the items in cart and store as array list:

```
public ArrayList<shopManagement.entity.Cart> getCartItems() {

    ArrayList<shopManagement.entity.Cart> ft = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String dbQuery = "SELECT productID,quantity FROM sm_cart WHERE custName = '" + custName + "'";
    DBController db = new DBController();
    db.getConnection();
    rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            ft.add(new shopManagement.entity.Cart(rs.getInt("quantity"), rs.getInt("productID")));
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return ft;
}
```

And here is how I retrieve the items in array list:

```
ArrayList <shopManagement.entity.Cart> ft = cart.getCartItems();
    for(int count= 0; count< ft.size(); count++){
        int prodID = ft.get(count).getProdID();
        int quantity = ft.get(count).getQuantity();
    }
```

But I have no idea how to get the orderID and store the items which I get from cart into order. Can somebody guide me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `orderID` you have to generate

Comment: it's auto increment in database and that's the prob

Comment: you can get it after commit

Comment: @vels4j Sorry what do you mean by after commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inserting the data through `JDBC` then you can retrieve id using `getGeneratedKeys()` method.

More on the same [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-last-insert-id.html).

Comment: If you think my answer has helped you/will help you in solving your problem then you can accept is as correct answer.